# jQuery - can't select the right div

Tags: jquery

This is a pretty common issue, but I can't figure it out. Let me post my code first:

```
<div class="myDeskContentRate">
    <span class='myDeskContentStar'><img src='star.png'></span>
    <div class='myDeskContentRateCount'><span class='starCount'>1</span></div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('.myDeskContentStar').click(function(){
        $postId = $(this).attr('networkPostId');
        $this = $(this);
        $starCount = $this.next('.myDeskContentRateCount');

        $.post('/includes/classes/handler.php?do=networkPostStar', { postId : $postId }, 
        function(data){ $this.html(data); $starCount.nextUntil('.starCount').load('/includes/classes/handler.php?do=networkPostStarCount', { postId : $postId }); });
});
```

When a star is clicked it had to do the post and then the load, because it has to update the amounts of stars.

What my problem is, that I can't select the **span class='starCount'** inside of the div **class='myDeskContentRateCount'**.

I can get the **class='myDeskContentRateCount'** but that's not what I want. Is there a way for me to get the **span class='starCount'**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will hopefully solve your problem:

```
$starCount = $this.next('.myDeskContentRateCount').find('.starCount');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.myDeskContentRate > div.myDeskContentRateCount > span.starCount');
```

would select it. Other possibilities

```
$('div.myDeskContentRateCount').child('span.starCount');
$('div.myDeskContentRateCount').find('span.starCount');
```

Comment: This worked out perfectly too :) Since you were first you'll get the answer mark :)

Comment: Damn, doesn't work I see. I didn't notice that it's changing for all .starCount's. Therefore @loannis will get the right answer. His suggestion works.